# Simple Logistic Regression Questions

Tags: regression, logistic

## Problem

I want to estimate the probability of a user choosing a car or transit as a transport mode. Following is the output of the simple logistic regression:

[image]

I want to estimate the probability of choosing car (auto) if INVT for auto = 3, INVT for transit = 7, OVT for auto = 1, OVT for transit = 2.5,  OPC for auto =2 and transit fare = 3.

## What I tried

For the probability of choosing car when the user owns a car and work in suburbs, I am using INVT for auto, OVT for auto, OPC for auto and transit fare along with AO as 1 and DW as 0.

> The probability  = Pr = exp(1.45 - (0.00897*3) -(0.0308*1) -
>   (0.0115*2) -(0.00708*3) +(0.77 * 1) - (0.561*0))/(1+exp(1.45 -
>   (0.00897*3) -(0.0308*1) - (0.0115*2) -(0.00708*3) +(0.77 * 1) -
>   (0.561*0)))
>
> Pr = 0.893

## Question

Is this the right approach to find this probability? Or should I also include the INVT, OVT and OPC for transit as well?

Comment: You should imitate what you did to construct the variables used in the analysis.  If INVT is defined (as it probably should be) as the difference between INVT for transit and INVT for car, then you need to do that subtraction before you multiply by the coefficient.  So, that part of the sum would be -0.00897*(7-3).  But, it depends on how INVT was defined in the estimation.

Comment: I only have the results of the estimation. This question does not contain the original data used for estimation of coefficients. So, I am assuming that the data contained information on individuals who either used a car or transit and the reported in vehicle time, out of vehicle time, etc.

Comment: I would carefully read the description that came packaged with that table.  My guess is that INVT means INVT transit minus INVT car.  But, the general principle is that you construct the variables to make the prediction in the same way the variables were constructed to estimate the model.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:
You should imitate what you did to construct the variables used in the analysis. If INVT is defined (as it probably should be) as the difference between INVT for transit and INVT for car, then you need to do that subtraction before you multiply by the coefficient. So, that part of the sum would be -0.00897*(7-3). But, it depends on how INVT was defined in the estimation. – Bill

I only have the results of the estimation. This question does not contain the original data used for estimation of coefficients. So, I am assuming that the data contained information on individuals who either used a car or transit and the reported in vehicle time, out of vehicle time, etc. – umair durrani

I would carefully read the description that came packaged with that table. My guess is that INVT means INVT transit minus INVT car. But, the general principle is that you construct the variables to make the prediction in the same way the variables were constructed to estimate the model. – Bill